# Binding Ethereum node into a Rails app, get 'JSON::ParserError: 776'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ethereum

I'm new to the field, I'm trying [ethereum-ruby](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby) to bind Ethereum node into a Rails app.

I have a node running APIs via IPC like

```
geth --ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3"
```

and in Rails console I can do

```
client = Ethereum::IpcClient.new("#{ENV['HOME']}/.ethereum/geth.ipc")
```

but when I try `puts client.coinbase["result"]` I get and error:

`JSON::ParserError: 776: unexpected token at '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}`

Comment: The ethereum gem is pretty buggy recently. I suspect it to be a bug because [the exact same command used to work a few month ago](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1576/87).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the call to node resulted in error (no coinbase set?) and therefore there is no "result" field, only "error".

You can also check the other ruby ethereum library [ethereum.rb](https://github.com/marekkirejczyk/ethereum.rb). It was designed to be easy to use for the programmer.